# LWC date input not displaying properly

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield, date-picker

I am facing a issue with lwc input for date. the date picker dropdown is not displaying properly it is being cutout by windows taskbar. I want to display this date picker at top of the field instead of displaying at bottom side. I am unable to figure out html code for the date picker because it is added dynamically when click on date field.

```
<lightning-input type="date" name="input2" label={effectiveDateLabel} onchange={effectiveDateChangeHandler} value={mBillingPlan.MBP_ECD__c}></lightning-input>
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you increase the height of your component.

Comment: That is not the option because for that i had increase height it will not look good and there will be alot of space.